# access a list from a different script unity c#

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

Hello i was unable to find an answer that works for me anywhere. I am simply trying to access a list of strings from another script but when i run my code it says my list is empty (when it isn't). here's my code any help is greatly appreciated.

there is a lot of code so i am just going to post the code that is trying to access the list:

```
public class enemy : MonoBehaviour {
    public Node nodeScript;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        test();
        Debug.Log(nodeScript.FinalPath.Count);
    }
    public void test()
    {
        nodeScript.FinalPath.ForEach(x => Debug.Log(x));

    }
}
```

this simply outputs to the console "0"
the other script is called Node and the list is called FinalPath.

Comment: What is `Node`?

Comment: how is the list created? have you linked the script through the editor? Do you need to grab the script inside the start method? Not enough information here

Comment: public List<string> FinalPath = new List<string>(); - this is how i'm initialising it. and i have linked it through the unity editor. and i am unsure if i need to grab it in the start method as the data inside the list changes throughout my programme

Comment: Node in the name of the script containing the list sorry.

Comment: @TomUnsworth sorry if I wasn't clear enough, you say the list is not empty, how is that list populated? You don't have to grab it in the start method, whilst more explicit, linking through the editor is enough.

Comment: if i am correct in thinking how a list is populated means how is data added to it; basically i have a method that finds a shortest path between two points then adds these to the list, then i move all of that data into my final path list.

Comment: Is your other script attached to the same game object ? Or to another object ?  In any case, you have to get actual *instance* of your script class. A script class will be instantiated for each instance of game object that it is attached. If you know you will only have one, you can also go for a `static` version, use `static` properties, and then you could access it easily with ClassName.Property (like `Node.FinalPath`).

Comment: To get your other script, you should be able to use `nodeScript = GetComponent("Node")` if it's on the same game object. This should go in the Awake or Start method. If it's not on the same gameObject, the you just need to use some GameObject.Find method and the call .GetComponent on the found object.

Comment: the two scripts are on different game objects, i cant use static as it says Node.Finalpath cannot be accessed with an instance reference, then it says  qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: so do i want to put GameObject.Find(nameofgameobject containing my list), then in the same start method put gameObject.getcomponent(finalPath);?

Comment: @TomUnsworth yes, except that in GetComponent() you have to write the name of the script atached to your gameObject. If I understood well, that should be GetComponent("Node") . This will give you the correct script instance, and then you can access the finalPath on this reference. I'll try to write a full answer.

Comment: void Start () {
        GameObject.Find("P1");
        gameObject.GetComponent("Node");
    }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
 
        
        nodeScript.FinalPath.ForEach(x => Debug.Log(x));
        Debug.Log(nodeScript.FinalPath.Count); now i have this but i am still just getting 0 outputted

Comment: @TomUnsworth The problem here is that you are not attaching the result of your Find and GetComponent method to your local variable. You should do :  `var yourOtherObject = GameObject.Find("P1"); this.otherNodeScript = yourOtherObject.GetComponent("Node");`

Comment: Sorry, I just understood something : you need another field in your class (let's say `private Node otherNodeScript`, I misunderstood something before. I edited my answer, please check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go fetch the correct instance of your other script, which is a component attached to some other game object.

Let's say the other game object with your `Node` script that has the correct `FinalPath` data is called "otherGameObjectName".

```
 public class enemy : MonoBehaviour {
    public Node nodeScript;
    private Node otherNodeScript; // Add this 

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        otherNodeScript = GameObject.Find("otherGameObjectName").GetComponent<Node>(); // Here bind your local Node reference to the actual instance
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        test();
        Debug.Log(otherNodeScript.FinalPath.Count); // change here
    }

    public void test()
    {
        otherNodeScript.FinalPath.ForEach(x => Debug.Log(x)); // change here

    }
}
```

This is supposing that the other game object already exists when the enemy object is created.

There are other ways to find your other script, that have better performance, but this should fit for your need at the beginning, to let you understand how the reference to other objects work.

Some reference :

[GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)

[GameObject.Find](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html)

Comment: working! thank you so much.